Rename JarLauncher in Spring Boot App packaged by jpackage
I created a spring boot web application. This application should be installable and runnable through a dmg file. The name of the application should be visible in the task bar on MacOS.
I used the program jpackage to create a dmg file that makes the application installable. I'm able to install the app and run the app. In the task bar the name of the app ist visible but when opening the Context Menu in the task bar it sais 'About JarLauncher' and 'Quit JarLauncher'. I think this is because the main class of the jar-file ist the spring boot JarLauncher class but I have no idea how to change it to my own app name.
I ran the following command to build the dmg:
jpackage --input target/ --name "My App" --main-jar myapp.jar --type dmg --icon icn.icns
The following screenshot contains an excerpt from the toolbar with the context menu that says 'About JarLauncher'.
Context Menu MacOS with JarLauncher name
Any ideas?

Maybe man jpackage and check out stuff like macOS platform options (available only when running on macOS):

It does work if you set the apple.awt.application.name property
e.g.
jpackage ... --java-options -Dapple.awt.application.name="$APP_NAME"

or Java code
System.setProperty("apple.awt.application.name", "SomeAppName");

